# Visualforce field value keeps changing after save

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller, campaign-member, inline-visualforce

I'm having an issue with my visualforce page updating values if after saving even if I don't update that value on the save instance. I think it may be that I have my Save method written incorrectly?

Example would be that it'll change the value 'sales working' to 'Sales+working' for any rows I did not update. But for the row that I had changed, it'll be the correct value. See screenshot below:

[image: adding plus sign in spaces]

Here is my controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountPricingRanges {

public List<CampaignMember> range {get;set;}

public AccountPricingRanges() {
    range = [Select 
             Id,
             Name, 
             Lead_Contact_Status__c , 
             Status_Update__c , 
             MQL_Date__c, 
             Campaign.Name, 
             Email, 
             CompanyOrAccount, 
             ContactID, 
             Shopping_Cart__c,
             LeadOrContactId,
             Alexa_Rank__c  from CampaignMember WHERE MQL_Date__c >= THIS_WEEK  LIMIT 100];
}

public pageReference save() {
    update range;
    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    return pageRef.setRedirect(true);
}

public PageReference cancel() {
    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    return pageRef.setRedirect(true);
}
}
```

And this is my visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountPricingRanges">
    <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" title="Marketing Qualified Leads">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/> 
                                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! range}" var="cm">
                <apex:column value="{!cm.Campaign.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cm.MQL_Date__c}"/>  
                <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!cm.LeadOrContactId}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Shopping Cart" value="{!cm.Shopping_Cart__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!cm.Alexa_Rank__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Lead/Contact Status">
                <apex:outputField value="{!cm.Lead_Contact_Status__c}"/>  
                </apex:column> 
               <apex:column headerValue="Update Status Here">
                <apex:outputField value="{!cm.Status_Update__c}"/>  
                </apex:column> 

            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
                    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I would check and see if there are any triggers, workflows, process builders, etc. for the Campaign Member object that are firing as a result of the update in your save method.

Comment: There were initially, but they have been turned off. The issue still persists. Can you give me an idea on why that would be a factor?

Comment: What is setting the status from 'Sales Working' to 'Sales+Working'? Is Status update a formula field?

Comment: That's where I'm unsure. There's nothing in the code that's doing it and the Process Builder updating that field has been deactivated